# Array not populating first header

Tags: vba, excel

My code below, to add in a series of column headers, does not add the first header "Account ID" to the first column. Instead, cell A1 is populated with "# Pmts."  I cannot find why this would happen.  My workaround at the moment is to add in a second "Account ID".

```
Sub Create_Transaction_Notes()

Dim DSA As Worksheet
Set DSA = Worksheets("DEBT_SALE_ACTIVITY")
Dim LF As Worksheet
Set LF = Worksheets("LOAD_FILE")
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim myCount As Integer

'Add in the column titles
DSA.Activate
myArray = Array("Account ID", "# Pmts.", "Total value Pmts.", _
    "Avg. Pmt. value", "# Purchases", "Total purch. value", _
    "Avg. purch. value", "# Cash adv.", "Total cash adv. value")

With DSA
    For myCount = 1 To UBound(myArray)
        .Cells(1, myCount).Value = myArray(myCount)
        Next myCount
    End With
```

Comment: Arrays in VBA start with 0 by default. Change your for statement to “For myCount = 0 To UBound(myArray)”

Comment: You beat me to it @JoeyGrant

Comment: Or you can use the ill-advised method of `Option Base 1`. Not recommended, but it's there.

Answer (score 2):

No need for loop:

```
[DEBT_SALE_ACTIVITY!A1:I1] = Array("Account ID", "# Pmts.", "Total value Pmts.", _
                              "Avg. Pmt. value", "# Purchases", "Total purch. value", _
                            "Avg. purch. value", "# Cash adv.", "Total cash adv. value")
```

Comment: Not to mention that this method is likely going to run much faster, esp if the array was larger. +1

Comment: Great solution, this works perfectly and I can see that this would be quicker when using a larger array.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in VBA start with 0 by default. Change your for statement to

```
For myCount = 0 To UBound(myArray)
```

Comment: The safest, fool proof method is to use `For myCount = LBound(myArray)  To UBound(myArray)` just as another method. I have made some of my arrays start with a number such as 15 for reasons unique to the program's situation. Doesn't happen often to have an offset lower bound, but it's possible.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for this.  I agree using the Lbound is a much better solution.  Cheers